# getting values from stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

i have this code:

```
 Dim parameterlist(1) As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter
 Dim selects As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter = New BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter("@p_where_strempid", "empcode=602256", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input)
 Dim wheres As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter = New BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter("@p_where_str2", "applicableyear=2014 and (applicablemonth between 1 and 2)", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input)

parameterlist(0) = selects
parameterlist(1) = wheres

Dim test As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedure = New BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedure("DatabasePAYNORTH1", "pMyApp1Tbl_myproced", parameterlist)


            If (test.RunNonQuery()) Then


                Dim outputParameter As System.Data.IDataParameter


                For Each outputParameter In test.OutputParameters


                    Dim outputValue As Object = outputParameter.Value

                    MsgBox(outputValue.ToString)


                Next


            Else
```

what is my error here?? when i run the code i got error in for each .. what is this error? i just only want to get my records in stored procedure. hope you can help me guys. thanks

Edited..

This is my stored procedure in sql server

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pMyApp1Tbl_myproced]
            @p_where_strempid nvarchar(4000),
            @p_where_str2 nvarchar(4000)
    AS 
    DECLARE
        @l_query_select nvarchar(4000),
        @l_query_from nvarchar(4000),
        @l_end varchar(4000)
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

            -- If page number and batch size are not valid numbers return the empty result set
            SET @l_query_select = 'SELECT  top 6 net from(select a.empcode,sum(a.netincome)as net,b.applicableyear,b.applicablemonth
                                   from  [tbl_fpPayrollDetails] a inner join tbl_fppayroll b on a.payrollno = b.payrollno where '
            SET @l_query_from=' group by empcode,applicableyear,applicablemonth ) as src where '
            SET @l_end =' order by applicablemonth , applicableyear '

            EXEC(@l_query_select + @p_where_strempid + @l_query_from + @p_where_str2 + @l_end);


        SET NOCOUNT OFF



    END
```

Comment: What is test, what is the code of RunQuery? Without these info it is difficult just to know if any Parameter exists at all. Are you sure that you are not confusing Parameters with the results of a SELECT query?

Comment: oh I am sorry it is my stored procedure.. here is my declaration of test:
Dim test As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedure = New BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedure("DatabasePAYNORTH1", "pMyApp1Tbl_myproced", parameterlist)</pre>

Comment: I have tried my stored procedure to run in sql server management studio and i got my results but when i tried to run it on visual studio i got nothing but error saying that test.outputparameters is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a procedure with output parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pMyApp1Tbl_myproced]
        @p_where_strempid nvarchar(4000),
        @p_where_str2 nvarchar(4000),
        @OutputParameterName int OUTPUT
AS
```

then to get the value back via an output parameter(s) you need to declare it as well as you did for input parameters.

```
Dim p As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter 
p = New BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter("@OutputParameterName", Nothing, System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output)    
'NOTE: if this parameter has a string type such as varchar, nvarchar, string, etc. you have to set its size:
'p.Size = 10

Dim parameterList(2) As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter
...
parameterlist(0) = selects
parameterlist(1) = wheres    
parameterlist(2) = p
```

RunQuery is used when a set of records is being returned.  RunNonQuery is used when one or more values are returned through output parameters.

So if you have no output parameters and you need to go through the data set and access each row and column, use

```
If test.RunQuery() Then
    Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet = test.DataSet
    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = ds.Tables.Item(0)
    Dim r As System.Data.DataRow
    For Each r In dt.Rows   
        Dim s as String = myRow.Item(0).ToString()  
    Next
End If
```

Comment: on that procedure the net columns retrieve data which is what i want to happen in asp.. please do help me

Comment: Your stored procedure has no output parameters. You should have e.g. @OutputParameterName int OUTPUT (see my post)

Comment: how can i get the 'net' column as my output?